# C#, How to add Pitch to SpeechSynthesizer.SpeakSsml(String)

Tags: c#, speech-synthesis, ssml

I use `SpeechSynthesizer.SpeakSsml(String)`.

However not able to build an SSML containing pitch.

So far I could not find any working example online.

Answer (score 3):

MS's Speech Synthesizer isn't built to do singing synthesis, but you can change the pitch characteristics using [the `<prosody>` element](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/polly/latest/dg/supportedtags.html#prosody-tag):

```cs
SpeechSynthesizer.SpeakSsml("<speak version=\"1.0\" xml:lang=\"en\"><prosody pitch=\"x-low\">Hello World</prosody>.<prosody pitch=\"x-high\">Hello World</prosody></speak>");
```

Comment: is it possible to add bit rate?